# Resize views in a layout

Tags: android

I have a horizontal linear layout with multiple image views. Is there a way to resize these views automatically, so that all of them fit inside the screen?
this is the code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/cinnamon"/>
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cinnamon"/>
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ham"/>
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

With all the image views make sure that you set the layout to whatever best fits your needs. Try "fill_parent". For width and height. Provide us with some code and a better description of the layout you want to appear to the user and we can give you better example of what you need. If this helps, let us know.

**Solution**

Set `layout_weight` to 1 for every image view.

Comment: I added a sample code. It's nothing complicated. I just want to have 3 (for example) image views, displayed horizontally. If the linear layout (or any other layout) exceeds the screen boundaries, the views should resize so that all of them can be displayed. Thanks!

Comment: Change the layout_width to fill_parent for all the images. Now the height might be a little more complicated but try changing it to fill_parent as well and see where that takes you. Let me know the results.

Comment: I did, and it's not working. The result is that the first image is wide as the whole screen.

Comment: I did it. The thing is to set layout_weight to 1 for every image view.